# Can osql.exe run as a standalone?

Tags: sql-server, osql

I have a program that runs osql.exe from microsoft sql server tools directory and runs a script.

The problem is that on computers that don't have an installation of sql server, this tool is missing. So my question is whether or not is possible to run it as a standalone( along with any dll that may be required ) meaning that run them from Process.Start from a local directory of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just copy the binary and off you go.

Comment: With SQL Server 2012 you need to also copy osql.rll, then it works. Default paths are `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\OSQL.EXE` and `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\Resources\1033\osql.rll`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you spawning osql?

I've written simple programs to execute scripts using SMO - mostly insired by [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/11/07/Handling-_2200_GO_2200_-Separators-in-SQL-Scripts-_2D00_-the-easy-way.aspx).

**EDIT**

The jist of the post is to use [SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms162169.aspx).  [`Server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection.executenonquery.aspx) parses SQL with `GO` statements in it.

Comment: its an already written application(not by me), and i don't want to switch its way of running the script.

Comment: It's a nifty way to test the right ports are open between servers.